# cannot assign void to implicitly-typed local variable

Tags: c#

Not sure what I am doing wrong syntax-wise here

```
        var inventories = new List<Inventory>().Add(new Inventory
        {

        });
```

Compile-time error:

> cannot assign void to implicitly-typed local variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`List.Add` returns `void`. Try

```
 var inventories = new List<Inventory>(){ new Inventory() };
```

Answer (score 2):

The return value of `Add` is `void`.

I think you meant to write:

```
var inventories = new List<Inventory>();
inventories.Add(new Inventory{

});
```

Comment: I'm trying to chain it, more elegant

Answer (score 1):

The return type of `Add()` is a void, i.e no return value, your code is trying to assign a reference to "nothing"

You have two options, declare the list, and then add to it

```
var inventories = new List<Inventory>();
inventories.Add(new Inventory());
```

or use an array initializer

```
var inventories = new List<Inventory>()
{ 
    new Inventory()
};
```

Comment: I couldn't think what was happening until you said "you're trying to assign a reference to 'nothing' then it came into focus. :)